# display:none is not consistent in outlook but works in chrome

Tags: html, css, outlook

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
            }            
            .delimiter {
                color: gray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
        <table align="center" width="800" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
                <td style="display: none;" bgcolor="#FFD500" align="left" width="25%"><img height="40px" src=""></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFD500" align="center" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; color: #000000; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 32px;font-weight: bold;" colspan="2">Hello World</td>
                <td style="display: none;" bgcolor="#FFD500" align="right" width="25%"><img height="40px" src=""></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is the HTML that is being used. The HTML is also copied directly over from outlook so the HTML for the outlook email and the chrome page is identical (same HTML).

This is what I get in chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nde2.png

This is what I get in outlook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l6tJ.png

The two HTML codes are the same though it works properly in chrome but not in outlook. It should display:none for both of the cells though it only does so for the image on the right but not the left.

It is also weird because it's not as if it doesn't work completely in outlook, it works for the cell/image on the right but not the left even though I've checked and they are pretty much identical. What could possibly be causing this?

I've also tried outlook conditional CSS (!--[if mso]> and <![endif]--) around my tr tags, but the same result.

Comment: Are you using outlook 2007 to 2016? display:none is not supported by Outlook (2007-2016) on Windows. You can try mso-hide:all on a <table> or <td> instead.

Comment: Yea it's odd because the display:none works when hiding the cell/image on the right, but doesn't work for the left counterpart. 

Also, I just tried using mso-hide:all, though it still gives the same result in outlook for some reason. 


`<td style="mso-hide: all;" bgcolor="#FFD500" align="left" width="25%"><img height="40px" src=""></td>`

Comment: What if you apply that to your table instead of the individual cells?

Comment: Then the entire hello world and yellow table goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I found this

```
style="display:none;width:0px;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;height:0;font-size:0;max-height:0;line-height:0;margin:0 auto;"
```

on [litmus.com](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6911-display-none-not-working-in-outlook)

i.e. throwing everything at the non-functioning of display: none on some versions at least of desktop Outlook.

I’m afraid I can’t test this for real at the moment so can’t say for certain that it’s an acceptable answer. Would be interested to know if it works in your situation.

Comment: Ah, I found that too. Though even after trying it, there is no difference. I still end up getting the blank space on the left side for some reason.